# Discrete Maths Functions

Tags: functions

Let $A = P(\{1, 2, 3, 4\})$. Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be the following functions.

$f : A \to A$ defined by $f(X) = X \cap \{3, 4\}$.

$g : A \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by 
$$
g(X) = 
\begin{cases}
−1  & \text{if $X = \{\}$}\\
\text{the greatest element of}~X & \text{if $X$ doesn't equal $\{\}$}
\end{cases}
$$

$h : \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to A$ defined by $h(x) = \{1, 2, 3, 4\} − \{x\}$.

1. (i) What is $f(\{2, 3, 4\})$?

   (ii) What is $g(\{1, 2, 3\})$?

   (iii) What is $h(4)$?

   (iv) What is $f \circ h(3)$?

My answer for part

i is $(\{3,4\})$,

ii is the greatest element of $X$,

iii is $(\{1,2,3\})$,

iv is $(\{1,4\})$.

What would be the ranges of the following though ?

(i) What is the range of f?

(ii) What is the range of g?

(iii) What is the range of h?

But I don't know whether it is right because I am confused about the domain and codomain.  Do correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In the image of $f$ we can only find subsets of $\{3,4\}$ so your answer on iv) cannot be correct. Concerning ii) write down the greatest element of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers for (i) to (iii) are correct, although in (iii) you might actually write the greatest element of the set $X=\{1,2,3\}$. For the last part, it should go as follows (and possibly the explanations will shed some light on how to solve this kind of questions):

$$\begin{align*}&(f\circ h)(3)&\\ &=f(h(3)) &\text{(by definition of composition of functions)}\\
&=f(\{1,2,3,4\}-\{3\}) &\text{(By the definition of the function $h(x)=\{1,2,3,4\}-\{x\})$}\\
&=f(\{1,2,4\}) &\\
&=\{1,2,4\}\cap \{3,4\} &\text{(By definition of the function $f(X)=X\cap \{3,4\}$)}\\
&=\{4\}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank u so much for explaining in depth for the last part !! .Glad to know i got the first three right .